# How to use wildcard for files without extension

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, command-line

I am completely stupefied by this.
I am running a weekly script to move log files into a directory.

```
mkdir 2022-04-30
mv *.* 2022-04-30/
```

when I do so - only files with extension are moved but not ones without.

If I try `*.` is says no files found

If I try `*` it does what I want but it also tries to move the directory `2022-04-30` into itself and prints an error. It doesn't affect script, but I would like to understand whats going on.

I am pretty sure `*` means zero or more characters. so `*.*` should move all the files and not directories.

Whats going on and how to make a script which does what I need without moving directories?

*CentOS 9 / bash*

EDIT:

file names example

```
2022-04-29abc.cde
2022-04-29 App
```

Comment: What you could do as a workaround depends a bit on what the other filenames look like.

Comment: I added filenames example. Not sure how file without extension is not the same as "filename." it should be same as "filename" looks a bit stupid. so basically no extension files should not be used in Linux if one to avoid unnecessary pain in the ... right? feels strange in 2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` means zero or more of any character, `.` means the single character dot. So `*.*` means any names with a(t least one) dot in there somewhere. On Unix-likes, the dot is just a regular character in filenames, and also there's no difference between files and directories in a regular glob. (If you wanted to match directories only, you could use `*/`.)

Here, it looks like the names of your files contain letters while the directories don't, so to target on that, you could
use `*[[:alpha:]]*` to match names that have at least one letter. That would still match directories, but would avoid names like
`2022-04-30`.

Alternatively, if what you're doing is something like `mv 2022-04-29* 2022-04-29` (i.e. move files starting with the date to a matching directory), you could instead use

```
mv 2022-04-29?* 2022-04-29
```

The `?` matches exactly one character, so `?*` requires at least one character after the date.

In zsh (but not in Bash), you could use `*(.)` to match just regular files (and similarly `*(/)` to match just directories). In all shells, `*/` would match only directories, but there's no equivalent for matching just regular files. (The slight difference is that with `*/` the names are produced with the trailing slashe.)

Answer (score 3):

`*` does mean zero or more characters

so `*.*` means some characters, followed by a dot, followed by more characters, so will match `foo.bar`, `foo.` `.bar`, `foo.bar.baz`, but not `foobar`, because the dot in the middle doesn't match anything in `foobar`, which is why it's not moving files without extensions

`*.` will then only match `foo.`, not `foo.bar`, because it's only looking for things that end in a `.`

To only move files and not directories, you'd be best off using something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` - this finds all files in the current directory (`.`), and not in subdirectories (`maxdepth` limits it, `maxdepth 1` means only the folder specified, `maxdepth 2` would include everything in a single layer of subfolders and so on), `-type f` filters to be regular files only

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} 2022-04-30/ \;` should work, although it's not pure bash so might not be portable to all systems

`-exec` for find executes whatever's after it, with {} being each result from the `find` command, in turn

(tested briefly with filenames which include spaces and newlines)

(edited to work with pathological filenames from comments)

Comment: there are spaces

Comment: thanks, I've edited it to suggest `-exec mv {} \;` with find instead of a subshell, which is more robust to spaces etc in file names

Comment: +1. FYI, like almost all Linux distros, Centos uses GNU versions of `find` and `mv`.  GNU `mv` has a `-t` option which allows you to put the target directory **before** all the filenames. That would allow you to write the find command as `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -t 2022-04-30/ {} +`. Using `+` instead of `\;` causes find to run the mv command with as many filenames as will fit into a command line (about 2 million chars) instead of once per filename.  Running `mv` only once (or maybe a few times with 1000s of files) is **much** faster than running `mv` hundreds or thousands of times